# How to build a rpm that installs host dependent files

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have to build **one** rpm that copies the contents of file `A` to `/path/to/tartetfile` if the hostname is *A*. In all other cases the contents of `B` should be copied to `/path/to/targetfile`. I'm aware that this may be a misusage of rpm, but I still have to do it like this. Do you have any ideas how to get this done in an elegant way?

My solution at the moment would be to create an empty `/path/to/targetfile` in my `BUILD` directory as well as a `/tmp/contents.tar.gz` that contains the files `A` and `B`. In the postinstall routine i then would extract the relevant parts of `/tmp/contents.tar.gz` to `/path/to/targetfile` and delete the tarball afterwards. In the pre-uninstall routine I'd then touch the `/tmp/contents.tar.gz` to supress rpm reporting errors for an already deleted file.

To me this seems to be a very dirty way to get this done. Do you have better ones?

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on abusing `rpm` for things it was not desinged for, you'll have to do dirty tricks.

I don't see another workaround for you. I fail to see the use of removing the tar.gz etc, unless that (little?) extra space is really a problem for you. I would propose:

- package all files (A and B) into some specific directory (`/usr/lib/your-package` or whatever), not in compressed format.
- in the `%post` section create just symlinks so that `/path/to/targetfile` points to `/usr/lib/your-package/A` or `/usr/lib/your-package/B` (symlinks take up almost no space). This has the additional value that `ls -l /path/to/targetfile` will show you which which file it points to, giving you the information whether this is file A or B.
- in your `%files` section declare `%ghost /path/to/targetfile` for a nice cleanup upon removal.

Comment: I agree 100%. Symlinks is the best approach, because that also helps with ownership and RPM DB queries.